# Nginx conf to manage traffic between 2 ssl'd endpoints

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

Here's the setup:
`fowarding_proxy`  -> `server_1`, `server_2`
`server_1` -> `app1.domain.com`, `app2.domain.com`
`server_2` -> `app3.domain.com`, `app4.domain.com`

Where each server is running a docker daemon with an nginx reverse-proxy based on the [jwilder/nginx-proxy  + letsencrypt setup](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion).

Both servers sit behind the same router and I need a way to route traffic correctly to each one based on the host name. I've been trying to use the nginx stream module since I don't want the forwarding proxy to handle any ssl termination, but the `$ssl_preread_name` directive doesn't (seem) to capture the host name on http traffic and I can't do a 301 on `server` directives in the stream module.   What's the best way to approach this?

I've included an example of the config I'm currently working with and I've tried multiple iterations.  Open to any suggestions.

(Also, as an aside, *nothing* logs to access.log)

*Forward_proxy nginx.conf*

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
  # bare bones content, still nothing written to the log.
  log_format main '[$time_local] $remote_addr'
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  map $ssl_preread_server_name $name {
    app1.domain.com server1;
    app2.domain.com server1;
    app3.domain.com server2;
    app4.domain.com server2;
  }
  
  upstream server1 {
    server server1:80;
  }
  upstream server2 {
    server server1:80;
  }
  upstream server1_ssl {
    server server1:443;
  }
  upstream server2_ssl {
    server server1:443;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    proxy_pass $name;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
  
  server {
    listen 443;
    proxy_pass "${name}_ssl";
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution, happy to hear of better ones.

Instead of a single forwarding-proxy, I created two new nginx containers:  One for HTTP traffic and the other for HTTPS traffic and put them both in a single docker-compose file for easier management.

HTTP-forwarding-proxy

```
http {
  map $host $name {
    default server1;
    app3.strangedreamsinc.com server2;
    app4.strangedreamsinc.com server2;
  } 

  upstream server1 {
    server server1_ip:8080;
  }

  upstream server2 {
    server server2:8080;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://$name;      
    }
  }
}
```

HTTPS-forwarding-proxy

```
stream {
  map $ssl_preread_server_name $name { 
    default server1;
    app1.strangedreamsinc.com server1;
    app2.strangedreamsinc.com server1;
  }


  upstream server1 {
    server server1_ip:8443;
  }
  upstream server2 {
    server server2_ip:8443;
  }

  server {
    listen 443;
    proxy_pass $name;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

I'm not convinced there isn't a better way and there's probably something I'm overlooking, but this allows me to transparently route traffic to the correct reverse-proxy and still supports the letsencrypt protocols to apply SSL to my servers.